# Magento XML build-up in plain english?

Tags: xml, magento, nodes

I've been reading about Magento and I understand the core flow of its request cycle etc.. (configuration based MVC and class overriding and such..) However, I cannot seem to find a good article/documentation on the specifics of things - especially when it comes to different nodes required to build the config.xml for custom module etc..OR anything on XML build-up. 
If anybody could direct me to the "real good stuff"..article, documentation, tutorial..anything please.

Thanks

Comment: I've written a bunch of articles over the years (http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) — but there's no one good source for this sort of thing, every module uses the config.xml in slightly different ways, which makes writing a master "here's everything you need to know" document/book challenging.

Comment: Thanks @AlanStorm BTW, i use your tool CommerceBug - Great Tool and a Big HELP! ;) So what is the best way about learning this though? Is it more about getting familiar with the structure/architecture?